# "has" matching node selector - helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Assume, we have two kubernetes environment, one is Windows based k8s cluster environment, other one is linux based k8s cluster environment. Both have different kubeconfig, not mixed up (not windows and linux in one k8s cluster).

Question:
if we deploy to windows based k8s cluster where the `nodeSelector` name is defined in the helm chart and it should use "kind: deployment". Using the same helm chart we used for windows k8s cluster, if we deploy to linux based k8s cluster, the appropriate `nodeSelector`name for linux is also defined in the helm chart and it should use "kind: daemonset".

How do we achieve using helm chart (with templates or _helpers.tpl) , is there an example i can see ?

Comment: While this seems like a slightly unusual setup – "exactly one replica on every node" tends to be a different use case than "some number of replicas spread across the cluster" – you can use Helm templating on any part of the Kubernetes YAML specification, including the `kind:`.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two separate clusters, In my helm chart, I might have the two manifests in my templates directory. I would use an `if` statement around my manifests to determine if that template is rendered. For example, have a value in `values.yaml` that specifies something like `nodeOS` and has possible values `windows` and `linux` you could then build a manifest like this

deployment.yaml

```yaml
{{- if eq .Values.nodeOS "windows" }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
... rest of manifest
{{- end }}
```

daemonset.yaml

```yaml
{{- if eq .Values.nodeOS "linux" }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Daemonset
... rest of manifest
{{- end }}
```

This would give you manifests in a single and you could determine what is rendered at install time by doing the below

`helm install <chart_name> . --set=nodesOS="windows"` (Would only deploy the deployment)

`helm install <chart_name> . --set=nodesOS="linux"` (Would only deploy the daemonset)